# How can I get the term_id from the action hook 'set_object_terms'?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, hooks, actions, terms

I have the following code and I want to use the term_id inside that function. I aware that the variable $terms contains the term; however, I do not know how to get the term id from it.

```
add_action('set_object_terms','wpse5123_set_object_terms',10,4);

function wpse5123_set_object_terms($object_id, $terms, $tt_ids, $taxonomy){
       if($taxonomy == 'category'){
           echo '<pre>';
           print_r($terms);
           exit;
       }
}
```

I tried the following but it does not work:

```
foreach (  $terms as $term) {
    $term_id[] = $term->term_id;    
}
```

Comment: Your own code should be sufficient to demonstrate that `$terms` isn't an object. It is, in fact already the array of IDs that you are trying to generate. If that is the only problem, you don't really have a problem.

Comment: @s_ha_dum `$terms` should have the id, but it doesnt. How can I get the id from `$terms`?

Comment: @Gixty `$terms` is exactly what you passed as 2nd argument to `wp_set_object_terms` (or `wp_set_post_terms`). If you passed to that function an array of term slugs, than you have to use [`get_term_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) to get term objects and then term ids from objects. If you pass an array of ids, then you already have the ids... If you pass a single value `$terms` will be an array of one element (an id if you passed and id, a slug if you passed a slug).

Comment: @G.M. Thank you. However, when I add a term, the `$terms` contains the term id, but when I remove it, `$terms` is empty. So, if it's empty, I cannot use it. How can I get the term id when removing it?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to delete all the `postmeta` related to the term being deleted.

For this, we need to use the action hook `'delete_term_taxonomy'` because it is executed before the term is deleted; therefore, we can find the term object and use it inside the hook.

Then, we proceed to perform certain task such as deleting all postmeta related to the term.

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'delete_term_taxonomy', function($tt_id) {

    $taxonomy = 'category';    
    $term = get_term_by('term_taxonomy_id', $tt_id, $taxonomy); 
    $user_name = $term->name;
    $meta_key = "_category_relation_added_" . $user_name;
    delete_post_meta_by_key( $meta_key );

}, 9, 1);
```